# Enforce referential integrity in MS Access vs Foreign Key Constrains in Microsost SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

Is Enforce referential integrity the same thing as  Foreign Key Constrains in MSSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access enforce referential integrity and SQL server forign key constraints are the same concept although SQL Server supports a more fleixible version of it.

SQL Server referential integrity supports multiple options when the parent record is altered: No Action, Cascade - on Delete and\or Update, set Null, set Default.  For more info see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-2017#FKeys

MS Access enforce referential integrity only supports the 'No Action' and 'Cascade' options. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guide-to-table-relationships-30446197-4fbe-457b-b992-2f6fb812b58f#bm9

Comment: You are awesome!